# MySQL CREATE TABLE FROM UNION gives "invalid default value"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table in an InnoDB MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to make a query with a union and store the result in a temporary table. I simplified it to the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result AS    
SELECT * FROM test
UNION
SELECT * FROM test
```

I add data like so:

```
INSERT INTO test (`date`) VALUES ('2017-09-01');
```

The response from MySQL is

```
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'date'
```

- Adding a default doesn't help (`date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2017-09-06'`).
- Without the `UNION` and the second SELECT it works.
- Using `UNION ALL` instead also works (but that's not what I need).
- replacing the DATE column with e.g. VARCHAR also works.

From what I read, 1067 is related to installation problems which is weird in this context.

What should I do in order to get this working?

Comment: Are you really selecting the same data from the same table or did you "simplify" it for the post?

Comment: This is not the query I actually need, I simplified it but it still throws the error.

Comment: Probably going to need the real query and sample values from the 2nd select to help you out.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Why? The table can be empty and the error is thrown. How do some extra WHEREs and JOINs help? Just executing those two statements throws an error that it IMO shouldn't.

Comment: It is version 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

Comment: @Tim-Erwin So... does it work if you actually have a record with a date value in `test`?

Comment: To be frank, it doesn't really matter what your opinion is of how it should work. If it's throwing an error it's obviously *not* working. And if you are obfuscating all of the query, data and other information except the error message how do you expect an answer?

Comment: Strange. Looks like a bug to me. It is working in 5.7.12, though: http://rextester.com/TEM41182

Comment: @AaronDietz, no, it doesn't. Added that to the question. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I'll try another version, thanks for trying it.

Comment: @JacobH, I'm obeying the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) principle here. I get an error and provide all details to reproduce it. If you think I shouldn't expect it to work, I'd be glad to know, why that is. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, would you mind putting your comment in an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @Tim-Erwin: Thanks, but it still is only a comment. I suggest you write an answer yourself and accept it, so future readers see what you found out :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in MySQL. The query is working in versions 5.6.25 and 5.7.12 but not in versions 5.7.17 and 5.7.19. So I assume this must be a bug that was introduced recently. (Reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87711) Thanks to Thorsten for the hint.

EDIT:

On my systems all 5.7. versions had the problem (yes, I tried them all ;) ). I couldn't go back to 5.6. So I switched to MariaDB which I can only recommend!